# Loading file sequence in cmd line

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

Could you help me with a very simple thing? I need to load a file sequence and execute an .exe file to render these files through cmd line. I know how to do all this. What I don't know is how to automatically load and render the next sequence file. For example after file0001.vrscene is rendered load file0002.vrscene and file0003.vrscene and so forth. There must be a simple Forloop with a variable. But since I don't work in batch i don't know how to set it up. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Try Like this :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set $c=1

for %%a in (*.vrscene) do (
  "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2015\vray\bin\vray.exe" -scenefile=%%a -imgFile="C:\Users\Beqarion\Desktop\test_for_batch\img!$c!.jpg" -autoclose=1
   set /a $c+=1
)
```

Comment: You'll need a `*` in front of `.vrscene`.